# How to backup specific MySQL table using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-backup, mysqlbackup.net

I have been doing backup of MySQL tables using [MySqlBackup.dll](https://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/) in C#. I have no idea on how to backup specific table inside a MySQL schema. How can I backup only one or two specific tables using C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this documentation section](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256466/MySqlBackup-NET#basicusage), you can specify it in the `MySqlBackup.ExportInfo` using the `List<string>` property called `TablesToBeExportedList`.

So, something like this should work:

```
string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=1234;database=test1;";
string file = "Y:\\backup.sql";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            mb.ExportInfo.TablesToBeExportedList = new List<string> {
                "Table1",
                "Table2"
            };
            mb.ExportToFile(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it also exported Functions and Views, how can I ignore Functions and View in the exported result?

Comment: I have to set those attributes to be `false`
```
                                mb.ExportInfo.ExportFunctions = false;
                                mb.ExportInfo.ExportViews = false;
                                mb.ExportInfo.ExportTriggers = false;
                                mb.ExportInfo.ExportEvents = false;
                                mb.ExportInfo.ExportProcedures = false;
                                mb.ExportInfo.ExportRoutinesWithoutDefiner = false;
```